# How can I change the appearance of the radiobutton like it looks in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, mozilla

I have a problem styling a radio button in HTML for Firefox. In Webkit/Blink it works fine. What do I need to use for styling options to look nice in Firefox? If possible I won't use JavaScript.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oh5uyevh/

For nice rendering use Chrome/Safari/Edge. For not so nice rendering use Firefox

Code:

**HTML**

```
<input class="color color-red" type="radio" name="accent_color_chooser" value="red">
<input class="color color-blue" type="radio" name="accent_color_chooser" value="pink" checked>
```

**CSS**

```
input.color {
  margin: 5px;
}

.color {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-appearance: initial;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}

.color:checked {
  border: 5px solid green;
}

.color-red {
  background-color: red;
}

.color-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: If doubled question, please post link and mark as duplicate.

Comment: You'll more than likely need to use a plugin for this. Not sure if Firefox supports direct styling of radio buttons.

Comment: http://cssdeck.com/labs/ldmtsmfk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use in your CSS the `[input type="radio"]` rule or maybe you can use [this online generator](http://www.csscheckbox.com/radio-buttons/0/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use something like [iCheck](http://icheck.fronteed.com/)
its easy to use.